# How to save the table data in local storage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to save the user input table data in to local storage using JavaScript.
I want to save user input in local storage,
Please see my code that I have tried,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue(){

        var selectedText = $("#ddlFruits").find("option:selected").text();
        if(selectedText!="None"){
            var display = document.getElementById("display");
             $('#display tr:last').after('<tr><th>'+selectedText+'</th></tr>');

document.getElementById('ddlFruits').selectedIndex = 0;


    }
}



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlFruits" onchange="getValue();">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Mango</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
</select>


<table border="1" id="display">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruits</th>
  </tr>r>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt of storing anything in your code. Looks like you haven't tried anything at all, and want someone to do the work for you.

Comment: You are right I did not tried because I am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IndexedDB to save values. IndexedDB is a built-in database, much more powerful than localStorage.

Please use following reference to get started:

- https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb
- https://javascript.info/indexeddb

If you want another option, you can use localStorage, you can use window.localStorage

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

  localStorage is simple. For your code you can use following code at the end of getValue
  function

```
window.localStorage.setItem('Fruit', selectedText);
```